# How to install Tor with Meek support on Ubuntu/Debian

Tags: debian, ubuntu

Is there any easy way to install and run Tor with meek support on Ubuntu? https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/meek

Beside it is possible to download the bundle archive I'm interested in a native way:

- Do I need any extra software to enable meek?
- how to configure torrc ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the moment the meek packages are landing in debian so we can expect them to arrive in ubuntu too.

**UPDATE**
Previous info are not working fine anymore, it looks there is now a repository for debian unstable ... so I changed my previous answer with this one:

**1 Add Repository**

[Repository](https://people.debian.org/~infinity0/apt/) (info on the repository page).

**2. Install `meek-client` package**

```
sudo apt-get install meek-client
```

**3. Update your tor configuration**

Now edit you tor configuration file `/etc/tor/torrc`:

```
sudo gedit /etc/tor/torrc
```

Add the meek plugin to it

```
ClientTransportPlugin meek exec  /usr/bin/meek-client
```

And some meek bridges:

```
Bridge meek 0.0.2.0:3 url=https://az668014.vo.msecnd.net/ front=ajax.aspnetcdn.com
Bridge meek 0.0.2.0:2 url=https://d2zfqthxsdq309.cloudfront.net/ front=a0.awsstatic.com
```

Comment: No, check out the variety of https websites that meek can connect through, in the Tor Browser. There's meek-amazon, meek-azure, and meek-google.

Comment: ok thanks, maybe they added recently, I will check it on march once I'm back in china.
If you have any knowledge about how to use meek with tor vanilla please share it.

Comment: For Ubuntu (not sure about Debian), I'd suggest that you also need to edit the AppArmor definition - otherwise you will get 'permission denied' errors. In the file `/etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/tor`, add the line `/usr/bin/meek-client ix,` at the end. Then restart AppArmor, or the whole machine.