# using pluggable transport 'obfs3', but we can't find a pluggable transport proxy supporting 'obfs3'

Tags: obfsproxy

```
root@alireza:# apt-cache policy tor obfsproxy 
tor:
  Installed: 0.2.4.23-1
  Candidate: 0.2.4.23-1
  Version table:
 *** 0.2.4.23-1 0
        500 http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ testing/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
obfsproxy:
  Installed: 0.2.11-1
  Candidate: 0.2.11-1
  Version table:
 *** 0.2.11-1 0
        500 http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ testing/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

root@alireza:# which obfsproxy 
/usr/bin/obfsproxy

root@alireza:# which tor
/usr/sbin/tor

root@alireza:# cat /etc/tor/torrc
ControlPort 9051
HashedControlPassword 16:********************************************* 
CookieAuthentication 0

##########Bridges List
UseBridges 1

#obfsproxy Bridges List
bridge obfs3 19*.***.***.***:1****
#ServerTransportPlugin obfs3 exec /usr/sbin/obfsproxy managed
```

error log

```
Sep 05 21:06:57.000 [warn] We were supposed to connect to bridge '19*.***.***.***:1****' using pluggable transport 'obfs3', but we can't find a pluggable transport proxy supporting 'obfs3'. This can happen if you haven't provided a ClientTransportPlugin line, or if your pluggable transport proxy stopped running.
```

Comment: I use this way and works perfectly ...
http://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/3723/obfsproxy-problem-in-ubuntu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with:

> ClientTransportPlugin obfs3 exec /usr/bin/obfsproxy --managed
>
> bridge 19*.***.***.***:1****

Comment: Thx, But not works with same error.

Comment: Well, make sure that you set up all correctly and make sure that obfsproxy is running.

Comment: Sorry, my obfs process was dead and i did not know about it ! , i use bridge like this and everything is ok now : bridge obfs3 1*.*.*.*    , Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When compiling OBFS proxy, you'll see a set of options, enabling or disabling some features, including obfs3, so try to compile it by hand from the [latest git tree](https://gitweb.torproject.org/pluggable-transports/obfsproxy.git)