# cannot upload pictures from directory : Permission denied. and apparmor

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration, directory

I am on Debian buster, running tbb 7.0.11 . This is a clean profile and everything. I wanted to upload a few pictures from /home/shirish/Pictures but when I tried to, it says/said the following -

```
Could not read the contents of shirish

Error opening directory '/home/shirish': Permission denied
```

I have no idea why this is so, hunting on the board/forum gave me the following query and answer.

[Directory Cannot be Readed: Permission Denied after update to 0.3.0](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/15185/directory-cannot-be-readed-permission-denied-after-update-to-0-3-0)

I do have apparmor installed but it seems it is like a dependency on something rather than something that I explicitly installed.

While the answer has been given therein, saying -

```
[Service]
AppArmorProfile=
```

It didn't explain the rationale or what that line does or do, no explanation.

Could somebody throw some more light on the matter. I do see the following after seeing [Could not launch managed proxy executable at '/usr/bin/obfs4proxy' ('Operation not permitted')](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/9520/could-not-launch-managed-proxy-executable-at-usr-bin-obfs4proxy-operation-n)

but do not have any undertanding of apparmor except what I could make from the description of it.

```
shirish@debian:/etc/systemd/system$ cat /lib/systemd/system/tor@default.service
[Unit]
Description=Anonymizing overlay network for TCP
After=network.target nss-lookup.target
PartOf=tor.service
ReloadPropagatedFrom=tor.service

[Service]
Type=notify
NotifyAccess=all
PIDFile=/var/run/tor/tor.pid
PermissionsStartOnly=yes
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/install -Z -m 02755 -o debian-tor -g debian-tor -d /var/run/tor
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/tor --defaults-torrc /usr/share/tor/tor-service-defaults-torrc -f /etc/tor/torrc --RunAsDaemon 0 --verify-config
ExecStart=/usr/bin/tor --defaults-torrc /usr/share/tor/tor-service-defaults-torrc -f /etc/tor/torrc --RunAsDaemon 0
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP ${MAINPID}
KillSignal=SIGINT
TimeoutStartSec=300
TimeoutStopSec=60
Restart=on-failure
LimitNOFILE=65536

# Hardening
AppArmorProfile=-system_tor
NoNewPrivileges=yes
PrivateTmp=yes
PrivateDevices=yes
ProtectHome=yes
ProtectSystem=full
ReadOnlyDirectories=/
ReadWriteDirectories=-/proc
ReadWriteDirectories=-/var/lib/tor
ReadWriteDirectories=-/var/log/tor
ReadWriteDirectories=-/var/run
CapabilityBoundingSet=CAP_SETUID CAP_SETGID CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE CAP_DAC_READ_SEARCH
```

I have no idea if I'm barking up the wrong tree altogether.

Any help/guidance in the matter would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't have an answer to your question. But I can tell you that Tor Browser runs its own copy of Tor in the background. Therefore, editing systemd files for the **system's** Tor process will not help.

Comment: Are you using `torbrowser-launcher`? If so, it has its own apparmor profile that might be the source of this issue. Also if it *is* apparmor you should have a corresponding output in your logs, if you run like `dmesg | grep -i apparmor` or similar and see if it has anything related to access to that folder being denied and which profile caused it.

Comment: aha, thank you for the pointer, didn't know that. It indeed seems to be the case. see https://paste.debian.net/1003344/ for more. I don't know about audit bit in dmesg hence have obfuscated the numbers with xxx's . I hope you can help me in understanding what is happening here.

Comment: There seems to be lot of denials therein, are all of those from firefox's own apparmor profile or apparmor from Debian, anyway to know which is from where ?

Comment: If they're affecting Tor Browser, they're from the `torbrowser-launcher` profile, which is installed with it. Do you need anything specifically about it trying to access ~/Pictures? I don't see it allowing that anywhere: https://github.com/micahflee/torbrowser-launcher/blob/master/apparmor/torbrowser.Browser.firefox